# Can't get angular.js to loop through array and post to html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Edit: changed ng-controller to ng-app in body tag, was typo

---

I'm new to angular and im trying to use ng-repeat to post all items in the `products[]` to html but the `{{expressions}}` come out as text rather than computing.

I don't have my laptop so I'm testing all this on jsfiddle and w3school's editor from my phone.  Maybe it's the editors?  Sometimes they seem inconsistent.  I'm following 'Shaping Up Angular' on CodeAcademy and w3school's tutorials and and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myStore">

  <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">

    <div ng-repeat="x in store.products">
      <h1>{{x.name}}</h1>
      <h2>${{x.price}}</h2>
      <p>{{x.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myStore', []);
app.controller('StoreController', function(){
   this.products = [
      {
       name: 'keyboard',
       price: 20.47,
       description: "well made from scratch",
       reviews: [
               {
           stars: 5,
           body: "great fantadtic worksmanship",
           author: "global@gmail.com"
               },
               {
           stars: 4,
           body: "amazing sale for the best",
           author: "insign@gmail.com"
               }
           ];
     },
     {
       name: "bed",
       price: 250.69,
       description: "sturdy contriction from panama",
       reviews: [
               {
           stars: 2,
           body: "could be better",
           author: "john@gmail.com"
               },
               {
           stars: 1,
           body: "shitty",
           author: "carmen@gmail.com"
               }
           ];
     } ];
 } );
 </script>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some syntax errors:

```
var app = angular.module('myStore', []);
  app.controller('StoreController', function(){
     this.products = [
        {
         name: 'keyboard',
         price: 20.47,
         description: "well made from scratch",
         reviews: [
                 {
             stars: 5,
             body: "great fantadtic worksmanship",
             author: "global@gmail.com"
                 },
                 {
             stars: 4,
             body: "amazing sale for the best",
             author: "insign@gmail.com"
                 }
             ]//remove this: ;
       },
       {
         name: "bed",
         price: 250.69,
         description: "sturdy contriction from panama",
         reviews: [
                 {
             stars: 2,
             body: "could be better",
             author: "john@gmail.com"
                 },
                 {
             stars: 1,
             body: "shitty",
             author: "carmen@gmail.com"
                 }
             ]//remove this;
       } ];
   } );
```

See working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/a1f4i0ayEddwTHkBCzQ8?p=preview

Comment: I didn't know you don't end nested/internal arrays with semi-colon, thanks.  If I didn't have to use my phone I could use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your `html` tag to  `<html ng-app="myStore">` and change `<body ng-controller="myStore">` to `<body>`. This is because `myStore` is a `module`, not a `controller`

Update

Exist some unexpected semicolons at each `reviews` array

It works on this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5hnciX46Hb5wLwDn4R6K

Comment: Mistyping is my biggest barrier to learning code.  I change ng-controller to ng-app in the html tag but wouldn't I have to put the controller in the body tag or another wrapping element?  I just tried both ways and still got the same results

Comment: Also is there a reason I cant use the body tag rather than html for ng-app?

Comment: You can use the ng-app in the body or on a div that contains all the controllers, for this situations a good debugger tool is needed. On the end of each `reviews` array exist an unexpected semicolon, I have created a plunker I'll update on the answer

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you're not supposed to use semi-colon for inside arrays.  I guess technically @bluetoft gets the accepted answer (by a split second) but I'm upvoting both because you caught the other error (both errors actually).  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What the other folks said, you have some syntax errors. I removed the semicolons from within this.products and it displayed just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myStore">

  <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">

    <div ng-repeat="x in store.products">
      <h1>{{x.name}}</h1>
      <h2>${{x.price}}</h2>
      <p>{{x.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myStore', []);
app.controller('StoreController', function(){
   this.products = [
      {
       name: 'keyboard',
       price: 20.47,
       description: "well made from scratch",
       reviews: [
               {
           stars: 5,
           body: "great fantadtic worksmanship",
           author: "global@gmail.com"
               },
               {
           stars: 4,
           body: "amazing sale for the best",
           author: "insign@gmail.com"
               }
           ]
     },
     {
       name: "bed",
       price: 250.69,
       description: "sturdy contriction from panama",
       reviews: [
               {
           stars: 2,
           body: "could be better",
           author: "john@gmail.com"
               },
               {
           stars: 1,
           body: "shitty",
           author: "carmen@gmail.com"
               }
           ]
     } ];
 } );
 </script>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, i wish i could upvote your guys answer, i think i need 15 rep to do that